# How to wrap two elements in jQuery by respecting their parent?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to wrap two elements in jQuery. Sometimes there is the case that an exact duplicate of the parent exists which is not visible. In this case the element from the invisible div gets wrapped too but in the visible one:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!$('#bottom-wrapper').length) {
      let buttons = $('.btn-1, .btn-2');
      buttons.wrapAll('<div id="bottom-wrapper" />');
    }
    $('#description').remove();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="description">Wait for 3 seconds to see the error - now its not wrapped, after 3 seconds it is</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn-1">To cart</button>
  <button class="btn-2">To checkout</button>
</div>
<div class="parent" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <button class="btn-1">To cart</button>
  <button class="btn-2">To checkout</button>
</div>
```

How can I change this so that it gets wrapped in each element? The problem is that the elements are generated in my code so there is no way to select them by class or something like this...

**UPDATE**
The timeout is not in the actual code!!! It's only here to show you the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the button children of the `.parent` so the buttons get wrapped in both containers separately.

However because you have 2 bottom-wrapper elements now you can't use id anymore so use class instead (Id's have to be unique).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!$('.bottom-wrapper').length) {
      $('.parent').each(function(){
        $(this).children('.btn-1, .btn-2').wrapAll('<div class="bottom-wrapper" />');
      });
    }
    $('#description').remove();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="description">Wait for 3 seconds to see the error - now its not wrapped, after 3 seconds it is</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn-1">To cart</button>
  <button class="btn-2">To checkout</button>
</div>
<div class="parent" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <button class="btn-1">To cart</button>
  <button class="btn-2">To checkout</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

(If I understand correctly) a generic solution is to find the parents of all desired elements. jQuery will remove any duplicates. Then for each parent, find the desired elements and wrap them:

```js
$(function() {
  var $parents = $('.btn-1, .btn-2').parent();
  // in the example HTML there are 5 matching elements
  // but 3 parents
  $parents.each(function() {
    $(this).find('.btn-1, .btn-2').wrapAll('<div class="bottom-wrapper"></div>');
  });
  console.log($("#demo").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p>.parent #1</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <button class="btn-1">To cart</button>
    <button class="btn-2">To checkout</button>
  </div>
  <p>.parent #2</p>
  <div class="parent" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <button class="btn-1">To cart</button>
    <button class="btn-2">To checkout</button>
  </div>
  <p>.parent #3</p>
  <div class="parent" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <button class="btn-1">To cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```